# Microsoft Dynamics Error: Developing SSRS report using Report Data Provider

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, aot

I am trying to create a class coding in AOT in my Microsoft Dynamics AX. What I am doing is to develop a SSRS report in Microsoft DynamicsAX 2012. Hence, for practice purposes I am actually following through this tutorial link: http://www.dynamics101.com/2013/09/developing-ssrs-report-using-report-data-provider-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/. Please Help. THank you

However, I am getting a syntax error that says:

> Syntax error
>   \Classes\CustReportRDPDemoDP\classDeclaration
>   classDeclaration
>   Err:9999

The error occurs at this code line:

> [SRSReportDataSetAttribute(tablestr('CustReportRDPDemoTmp'))]

My following code is as follows:

```
class CustReportRDPDemoDP extends SRSReportDataProviderBase
{
//Temproaray table buffer
CustReportRDPDemoTmp custReportRDPDemoTmp;

[SRSReportDataSetAttribute(tablestr('CustReportRDPDemoTmp'))]

public CustReportRDPDemoTmp getCustReportRDPDemoTmp()
{

    select * from custReportRDPDemoTmp;
    //return the buffer
    return custReportRDPDemoTmp;
}

///<summary>
/// Processes the SQL Server Reporting Services report business logic
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This method provides the ability to write the report business   logic. This method will be called by
/// SSRS at runtime. The method should compute data and populate the data tables that will be returned
/// to SSRS.
/// </remarks>
public void processReport(){
    CustTable custTable;
    SalesTable salesTable;

    //select all customers
    while select * from custTable
    {
        //clear the temporary table
        custReportRDPDemoTmp.clear();
        //assign customer account and name
        custReportRDPDemoTmp.CustAccount = custTable.AccountNum;
        custReportRDPDemoTmp.Name = custTable.name();
        //select count of invoiced sales order of customer
        select count(RecId) from salesTable
        where salesTable.CustAccount == custTable.AccountNum
        &amp;&amp; salesTable.SalesStatus == SalesStatus::Invoiced;
        custReportRDPDemoTmp.SalesOrderInvoiceCount = int642int(salesTable.RecId);
        //insert in temporary table buffer
        custReportRDPDemoTmp.insert();
       }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have 3 separate methods, you can't just throw the code in the classDeclaration method.

The classDeclaration should just be:

```
class CustReportRDPDemoDP extends SRSReportDataProviderBase
{
    //Temporary table buffer
    CustReportRDPDemoTmp custReportRDPDemoTmp;
}
```

and the two other code blocks should be their own methods.